# How to communicate between Qt & iOS?

Tags: ios, macos, qt

I want to use iOS native code in my Qt application.For this need some help from you experts.
  I just want to call an native IOS code i.e. in objective C.
  Give me some code for calling an objective c function from Qt and that function should return some   value.

Please help me with some code snippet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use code you have written in Objective C in Qt just put the files under `OBJECTIVE_SOURCES` instead of `SOURCES` in the `.pro` file and suffix the file as `mm`

Example application using c++ and objective C from Qt  >>> https://github.com/richardmg/qtdd13_qmlapp